# What's the best force-directed network graph engine for large data sets?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html5-canvas, force-layout, vivagraphjs

I have looked at d3.js, but it seems to not work well for large data sets. I might try to switch from svg to a canvas and see the effect, does anybody have any insight on how well this works for large data sets.

Or should I look into vivagraph.js or another graphing engine?

Additionally I saw similar posts on the same question, but the answers were from 3 years ago, so I'm looking to see if anything new is better.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your definition of large, D3 might still work for you. If you leverage canvas, you can get to the low thousands of nodes and 10,000 or so edges:

http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/e330141d1279c6115a3a
http://emeeks.github.io/introspect/block_block.html

If you're dealing with more than that in the browser, there are some interesting solutions on the horizon that use WebCL and WebGL like https://github.com/Superconductor/superconductor that can do massive networks and edge bundling and such.

Comment: could you locate an example of edge bundling with super conductor?
any with pixi.js ?